# ¿Como crear array de "x" numeros decimales entre lo valores "y" y "z"?

Tags: python

Quiero obtener un array de números decimales entre dos valores, (or ejemplo 2000.00 y 2100.00). No sé como hacerlo : Por lo momento tengo dos alternativas, nunca me dan lo que quiero :

```
import numpy as np
import random
import decimal
all_values = np.array([2000*np.random.random(3) for i in range(10)])
print all_values
```

me da :

```
[[ 1237.71422998   858.3542556   1695.09000406]
 [  514.20215484   516.17059591  1512.52499356]
 [  744.42314666  1232.74944277  1434.53144762]
 [ 1201.13668055  1079.46214307   712.08913567]
 [  476.53854297   581.41400812  1512.70774028]
 [ 1202.66565767   209.74780245  1371.3482648 ]
 [  155.01843411   155.92438582  1149.84599247]
 [ 1866.7402305    159.65721067  1142.88608352]
 [ 1388.39461687  1677.20085145  1467.13341664]
 [ 1957.88998384  1041.01827722  1483.86465783]]
```

Y por un otro lado con :

```
import numpy as np
import random
import decimal
all_values = np.array([decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(200000, 210000))/100
 for i in range(3)] )
print all_values
```

Obteno solo una linea de tres decimales :

```
[Decimal('2093.56') Decimal('2013.24') Decimal('2028.18')]
```

No sé porque tenemos "Decimal" y como  desecharlo.

En definitiva quiero crear un fichero con las valores de tres "cryptocurrencies" para algunas ejercicios :

```
{"BTC":{"USD":2167.85},"ETH":{"USD":167.88},"DASH":{"USD":102.31}}
{"BTC":{"USD":2175.15},"ETH":{"USD":168.08},"DASH":{"USD":102.24}}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no se me escapa algo creo que [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html#numpy.random.uniform) te puede venir perfecto:

```
import numpy as np

all_values = np.random.uniform(2000.00, 2100.00,[3])
print all_values
```

**Salidas ejemplo:**

> [ 2002.54039356,  2026.36795063,  2022.74512326]
>   [ 2097.12514304,  2057.80636756,  2028.92052107]

El primer parámetro es el limite inferior, el segundo el límite superior. Todas las salidas son **mayores o iguales al límite inferior** y **menores que el límite superior**.

El tercer parámetro permite indicar el número de elementos que queremos y permite obtener matrices de cualquier cantidad de ejes:

```
>>> np.random.uniform(2000.00, 2100.00,[2, 3])
array([[ 2082.64829689,  2014.76782067,  2013.11257976],
       [ 2053.63698939,  2035.80081331,  2092.53029042]])

>>> np.random.uniform(2000.00, 2100.00)
2041.0258945855817
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Y como hacer para obtener algunas lineas en el mismo array ?

Comment: @Marine1 ¿Te refieres a obtener una matriz n x m?, ¿varias filas de tres elementos por ejemplo?. Si es eso mira la edición que acabo de hacer. Basta con pasarle las dimenciones del array de salida en el tercer parámetro. Saludos.