# Array de numeros

Tags: javascript

Chicos! tenga esta consigna
"La función llamada 'mayorMenor' recibe como argumento un arreglo de números llamado 'numeros' y debe devolver unarreglo que contenga el mayor número del arreglo 'numeros' en la posición uno y el menor número del arreglo
'numeros' en la posición cero.
Ej:
`mayorMenor([9, 17, 6, 2, 4])` debe retornar [2, 17]
ya que 17 es el número más grande (mayor) dentro del arreglo [9, 17, 6, 2, 4]
y 2 es el número más chico (menor) dentro del arreglo [9, 17, 6, 2, 4]"

Y tengo este código.. pero me da error... alguna idea?

```
    function mayorMenor(numeros) {
    var menor = numeros[0];
    var mayor = numeros[1]; 
    var array= [mayor, menor]
    for (var i = 1; i< numeros.length; i++){ 
     if (numeros[i] >mayor){
     mayor =numeros[i]; 
    } else if (numeros[i] < menor){
          menor = numeros[i]; 
      }
    return array;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: Tu ciclo `for` termina en la primera iteración, ya que tienes una sentencia `return` dentro del mismo. Eso como primera observación.

Comment: Esto ya se ha preguntado antes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/442997/54039

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como crear array de "x" numeros decimales entre lo valores "y" y "z"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73838/como-crear-array-de-x-numeros-decimales-entre-lo-valores-y-y-z)

Answer (score 3):

**PROBLEMA**

Uno de los problemas que veo en tu implementación es que asumes muy pronto que el primer elemento sea el menor y el segundo el mayor:

```js
var menor = numeros[0];
var mayor = numeros[1];
```

Otro problema es que tienes una sentencia `return` dentro de tu bucle `for`:

```js
for(var i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if( ...) { ... }
    else  { ... }
    return ... // <- esto finaliza la función justo en la primera iteración.
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Primero vamos a corregir la asunción errónea de que el primer elemento es el menor y el segundo es el mayor. Dado que no sabes a ciencia cierta qué número será mayor y qué número será menor.

Por lo tanto, puedes decir que el primer elemento es el mayor y a la vez es el menor, y al recorrer el `Array` actualizarás según sea necesario.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
  var menor = numeros[0];
  var mayor = numeros[0];
  ...
}
```

Ahora podemos recorrer el `Array` desde el primer elemento, tal como lo estabas intentando hacer, pero evitaremos usar la sentencia `return` dentro del ciclo `for`:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
  var menor = numeros[0];
  var mayor = numeros[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] > mayor) {
      mayor = numeros[i];
    }
    if(numeros[i] < menor) {
      menor = numeros[i];
    }
  }
  return [menor, mayor];
}
```

Como puedes observar, no estoy usando una estructura `if ... else`, ya que cuando esté recorriendo el `Array` sólo me interesa actualizar el caso cuando el valor sea mayor o cuando sea menor, y por lo tanto si no se cumple una condición se verificará la siguiente. ¿Sabes que pasa si no se cumple ninguna de las 2 condiciones?

Al final el resultado será el siguiente:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
  var menor = numeros[0];
  var mayor = numeros[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] > mayor) {
      mayor = numeros[i];
    }
    if(numeros[i] < menor) {
      menor = numeros[i];
    }
  }
  return [menor, mayor];
}

let listaDeNumeros = [
  [9, 17, 6, 2, 4],
  [17, 9, 6, 2, 4],
  [1],
  [10, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

listaDeNumeros.forEach(numeros => {
  console.log(mayorMenor(numeros));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Extra**

En Javascript disponemos de las funciones [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) y [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), que devuelven el elemento menor y mayor de una lista de números. Supongo que no te han permitido usarlas, pero no está demás conocer su existencia. El código podría quedar simplificado así:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
  return [Math.min(...numeros), Math.max(...numeros)];
}

let listaDeNumeros = [
  [9, 17, 6, 2, 4],
  [17, 9, 6, 2, 4],
  [1],
  [10, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

listaDeNumeros.forEach(numeros => {
  console.log(mayorMenor(numeros));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el código anterior he utilizado la [Sintáxis Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), para convertir el `Array` de números en una lista de argumentos que son pasados a las funciones `min()` y `max()`:

```
Math.min(...numeros)
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 2):

El primer error que veo, es que el array que retornas, lo tienes invertido. `[mayor,menor]` en vez de `[menor,mayor]`
Por otra parte, defines el array de retorno al inicio, y no al final cuando las variables `menor` y `mayor` ya tiene los valores correctos.
Además, el return lo haces dentro del bucle, y no cuando termine.
Y para finalizar, inicializas la variable `mayor` con el segundo valor del array, de manera que si el mayor fuera el primero, no funcionaria.
El código solucionado se parecería a este:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
  var menor = numeros[0];
  var mayor = numeros[0]; 
  for (var i = 1; i< numeros.length; i++){ 
    if (numeros[i] > mayor){
      mayor = numeros[i]; 
    } else if (numeros[i] < menor){
      menor = numeros[i]; 
    }
  }
  var array= [menor,mayor]
  return array;
}

console.log(mayorMenor([17, 9, 6, 2, 4]));
```

Ten en cuenta que esta función da por supuesto que el parámetro introducido es un array de números de al menos dos valores.

Por otra parte, el còdigo puede ser fas sencillo. Para facilitar la tarea de buscar el numero mayor y menor, es mejor tener la lista de números ordenada, de esa manera solo hay que elegir los valores de las esquinas del array.
Para hacer eso, los objetos tipo Array tiene el método sort, aunque como trabajamos con números y no letras, habrá que definir la función de orden.
Por ejemplo:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
  var numerosOrdenados=numeros.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
  var menor = numerosOrdenados[0];
  var mayor = numerosOrdenados[numeros.length-1];
  return [menor,mayor];
}
console.log(mayorMenor ([9,17,6,2,4]));
```

Ten en cuenta que en esta función de ejemplo, se da por supuesto que el parámetro contiene un valor correcto.

**EDIT** La solución más sencilla es la que indica @Mauricio-contreras, usar `Math.min` y `Math.max`.
Si ese problema es un ejercicio, antes de usar estos métodos deberías consultarlo con el profesor o profesora, si el tema tratado son las matrices y bucles, esperará una respuesta usando matrices y bucles, no un "copiar/pegar" de internet.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de resolverlo, pero lo ideal en cuanto a performance sería hacer una sola iteración completa, que en este caso es posible. Cualquiera sea la forma de hacer esa única iteración, javascrip tiene la posibilidad de comparar numeros con `Infinity`. Entonces una posible forma podría ser:

```js
const numeros = [9, 17, 6, 2, 4];

const res = numeros.reduce((p,c)=>{
if(c<p[0]) p[0] = c;
if(c>p[1]) p[1] = c;
return p;
},[Infinity, -Infinity])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicación de las correciones dentro del código:

```js
function mayorMenor(numeros) {
    var menor = numeros[0];
    var mayor = numeros[1];
    // 1. variable innecesaria
    //var array = [mayor, menor]
    // 3. iterar desde i = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] > mayor) {
            mayor = numeros[i];
        } else if (numeros[i] < menor) {
            menor = numeros[i];
        }
        // 2. El return debe estar afuera del for
        //return array;
    }
    // 2.1 retornar nuevo arreglo
    return [menor, mayor]
}

console.log(mayorMenor([17, 9, 6, 2, 4]))
```

Comment: Si paso como argumento el siguiente array: `[17, 9, 6, 2, 4]`, tu función falla.

Comment: Si paso como argumento el siguiente array: `[17]`, tu función devuelve: `[17, undefined]`, cuando debería devolver: `[17, 17]`.